# Update available message after installing update

Tags: updates, 13.04, do-release-upgrade

I have just updated my HTPC to 13.04 (using `do-release-upgrade`) and when logging in I get the "new release available" message, while there isn't as I've just upgraded and running that version.

```
me@mybox: ~$ssh htpc
me@htpc's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 13.04 (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-19-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

New release '13.04' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

So I am at 13.04, but I can upgrade to 13.04. Sounds like a plan. Or not.

I have done an `apt-get update` and `upgrade` (was nothing new) and rebooted the machine. Why is this message still here, and what needs fixing so it goes away?

For more info maybe:

```
htpc:~$ uname -a
Linux HTPC 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:19:42 UTC 2013 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It looks like the culprit is `/etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade`

This calls `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd`

This file checks for the file `/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available`

If that exists, it goes in the `motd`. If it doesn't, it calls `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release`.

That last command does give the right result, but the file was not removed for some reason. I removed the file and re-ran the commands. The msg-of-the-day wasn't put back.

So the final issue was the 'cache' of 'update needed' wasn't cleared.

I removed this file and it was fixed without breaking anything :)

```
sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available
```

This was a 12.10 -> 13.04 upgrade. On my other box (12.04 LTS, having the same issue) I had to look in another location:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/release-upgrade-available
```

Comment: Used this method and it worked. Cannot accept until 2 days are over :)

Comment: Thanks for this thorough investigation. To clarify: doing `sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available` followed by `sudo /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd` fixes the stale message.

Comment: You shouldn't need (or even want to) remove that second one! It's a script that checks for new upgrades available (but only if it hasn't found one before and saved it). So only the one in `/var/lib/` should be removed I think.

Comment: Right, remove the release-upgrade-available "flag" and then re-run the release-upgrade-motd script.

Comment: btw. should we / I submit a bug-report that the flag wasn't removed? Is this a thing that happens to all upgrades, or was it just a fluke?

Comment: Just FYI, there do appear to be bug reports in for it - [here's one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1173209). Looks like there's a fix in for 13.10.

Comment: Did not work for me, release-upgrade-available is recreated.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't an upgrade available?

Comment: Similar problem on release 18 to 20. Removing  that motd release flag file does not fix it. My problem seems to be with the python file `/usr/bin/hwe-support-status` - which generates the EOL messages for the MOTD. "You have packages from the Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) installed that are going out of support on 2025-04-30."/ETC -- See this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1908794

Answer (score 4):

if you open the file `/etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade`, inside you'll see that calls the bash `/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-motd`.
When you open this file inside we find this code:

```
stamp=/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available
if [ -s "$stamp" ]; then
        # Stamp exists and is populated, so display
        cat "$stamp"
        echo
elif [ -f "$stamp" ]; then
        # Stamp exists, but is empty, see if it's expired
        now=$(date +%s)
        lastrun=$(stat -c %Y "$stamp") 2>/dev/null || lastrun=0
        expiration=$(expr $lastrun + 86400)
        if [ $now -ge $expiration ]; then
                # But is older than 1 day old, so update in the background
                /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release -q > "$stamp$
        fi
else
        # No cache at all, so update in the background
        /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release -q > "$stamp" &
fi
```

stamp variable is populade by `/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available` file if exist or if it's empty else it check if exist a new release.
in `/var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available` if you open with text editor (`nano`, `vi` ...) you will find just the message that there is a new release of Ubuntu, so if you empty that or remove you force to check if there is a new release.

I hope I explained and sorry about my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

try `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
you may have that message in this file `/etc/motd`
If you are up to date, you can run `sodo rm /etc/motd` <-- edit if you have custom welcome text

Comment: Well, it is in the `motd` in fact (as it is the motd), but wouldn't that be cheating? the system believes it has an update for some reason, I'd like to find out why

Comment: if the 1st command does not find updates even after running `sudo apt-get update` and `lsb_release -sc` gives you `raring` you are update and the message is incorrect therefore should be removed

Comment: I agree. I just do not agree with your method of removing the motd ;)

Comment: +1 for pointing me to motd, not complete answer though, because it would have come back if I just removed that.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

1. `cd /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/`
2. `mv release-upgrade-available release-upgrade-available.old`
3. `cd /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/`
4. `./check-new-release`
5. Log Out/In

MOTD was back to normal.

Probably the same as above, but I don't like deleting things without fully knowing the consequences.  I'll just leave that file there, and wait for the 13.10 to prompt for upgrade in October.  Once I know that's working, I'll delete the .old file (or not, it's really not hurting anything).

Comment: the file is a flag, there's no need to do this at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a fix released, just run `sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude full-upgrade` and the message will be removed.

Comment: Doesn't this update your whole system? That's sounds a bit silly :) Anyway, this question was about what to do if the message doesn't go away. Good to know it probably won't be sticky again tough, but this might be better as a comment?