# Ubuntu 14.04 Interrupted Upgrade causing "No new release found"

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

Recently I was updating from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 from terminal. After starting the update, I accidentally closed the terminal process running it. It was the initial stage of the upgrade process and the required packages were being downloaded.

After this, when I opened the software updater, it was prompting for a partial upgrade. From my little knowledge, what I could make out was that the `/etc/apt/sources.list` was pointing to the new release which is Xenial. So I replaced the sources file with the `sources.bak` file available in the same location.

Everything looks alright now. But when I again try to upgrade using `sudo do-release-upgrade`, it is showing `No new release found`.

What can I do to fix the issue and make the upgrade work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was occurring not because of the interrupted upgrade. I restored my hard disk using the backed up image so that the traces of all the mess are cleaned up. But the same issue was still occurring. So I conclude that this is being caused by something else which must be the topic of this thread. [askubuntu question about the same](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801488/how-do-i-upgrade-from-14-04-lts-to-16-04-1-lts?rq=1)

However the above thread says that the bug causing this is resolved but I am still experiencing this.

Comment: I am encountering exactly the same problem.

Comment: did u resolve this? I faced it two times and both cases I was able to resolve. Couldnt remember what I done, but it was about deleting some caches or something

Comment: I haven't resolved it. Can you find out which caches you deleted?

Comment: is `apt-get dist-upgrade` working?

Answer (score 2):

Delete /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available and try the upgrade command again

```
sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/release-upgrade-available
```

In theory that should call /usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release.

Source - [Update available message after installing update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287939/update-available-message-after-installing-update/287949)

Comment: Tried... But still no luck. It is showing the same message. " No new release found" :(