# "do release upgrade" parameters

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

What is the exact meaning of adding the `-d` option at the end of `do-release-upgrade` command? The Ubuntu documentation defines it as:

> to upgrade to a development version of Ubuntu.

Once 16.04.01 is released, is there any difference in `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` and `sudo do-release-upgrade`?

I started my upgrade process from 14.04.05LTS to 16.04.01LTS using:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

After starting this, I read that:

> Upgrading to a development release is not recommended

Because of this I closed the terminal process doing upgrade. Now when I run `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`, I am able to resume the upgrade. But if I run `sudo do-release-upgrade` I am getting the message:

> no new release found

How should I resume the upgrade process correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` will upgrade you to the latest development version as you've read. Currently that is 16.10, named Yakkety Yak, which is being developed at the moment for release in October this year.

The best course of action is to check whether your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file has been modified by the `do-release-upgrade` command.

Check whether there are any references to Trusty in the file with:

```
grep -i trusty /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you get lines of output from this command, you are safe to run the following two apt-get commands to ensure that your packages for trusty are as up to date as possible:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Otherwise you will need to reset your sources.list file to its original form.

Now, check that your update manager is trying to go to the right release with:

```
grep -i prompt /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

You should see a line saying `Prompt=lts`. If that is there, then `sudo do-release-upgrade` should work.

Comment: I was upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04. Sorry for not mentioning that in the original post. I edited it now.

Comment: So I started an update from 14.04.05 to 16.10 ? Then realising that, I closed the terminal. But now I am able to resume only the interrupted upgrade. How can I stop the same and start the really intended upgrade?

Comment: It really depends how far it got through the process. You should probably do the `grep` command with the word `trusty` in place of `yakkety`. If you get some output, it's a good sign in this case.

Comment: Just now read your edit. The sources.list was pointing to xenial instead of yakkety. However I replaced it with its backup file which was pointing to trusty.  Now why `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` is suggested  instead of  `sudo do-release-upgrade` ?  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: The `apt-get dist-upgrade` was originally there when I thought you were going from 16.04 to 16.04.1. Ii is useful to use now to make sure that all of your packages for 14.04 are as up to date as possible before trying to move to 16.04.1.

Comment: Sorry to request for clarification, if I have resetted my sources.list to its original form, then how should I start upgrading? Can I use the dist-upgrade command in this case also?

Comment: No problem, I would do it to make sure 14.04 is up to date first. This will show you if any packages are broken. I would also reboot afterwards if it is successful.

Comment: Correctly interpreted the typo as `grep -i prompt /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` . Prompt is set us lts.  `Prompt=lts` . However `do-release-upgrade` still showing the `no new release found`  message. For this part of the error, I had this particular question opened earlier [link]http://askubuntu.com/questions/820795/ubuntu-14-04-interrupted-upgrade-causing-no-new-release-found[/link] . So there is still some impact of the interrupted upgrade left on the machine which I am not able to fix. Thanks anyway for all your  help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45298/discussion-between-erdnase-and-arronical).